# c++ How can I count the unique elements in a vector?

Tags: c++

I have this `c++` code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
struct szemelyadat {

    string vnev;
    string knev;
    int szulev;
    int szulhonap;
    int szulnap;
};

int vfmeret(const char* fajlnev)
{
    string temp;
    int merettemp = 0;
    ifstream meretBE(fajlnev);
    while (!meretBE.eof()) {
        meretBE >> temp;
        merettemp++;
    }
    meretBE.close();
    return merettemp;
}

void vfbeolv(szemelyadat* vek, int elemszam, const char* fajlnev)
{
    int i, j;
    string stemp, stempresz;
    ifstream adatBE(fajlnev);
    for (i = 0; i < elemszam; i++) {

        adatBE >> stemp;
        istringstream sorfolyam(stemp);
        j = 0;
        while (getline(sorfolyam, stempresz, ';')) {

            if (j == 0)
                vek[i].vnev = stempresz;

            if (j == 1)
                vek[i].knev = stempresz;

            if (j == 2)
                vek[i].szulev = atoi(stempresz.c_str());

            if (j == 3)
                vek[i].szulhonap = atoi(stempresz.c_str());

            if (j == 4)
                vek[i].szulnap = atoi(stempresz.c_str());

            j++;
        }
    }
    adatBE.close();
}

void vfkiir(szemelyadat* vek, int elemszam)
{
    cout << "Vezeteknev "
         << "Keresztnev "
         << "Szuletesiev "
         << "Szuletesihonap "
         << "Szuletesinap " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < elemszam; i++)

        cout << vek[i].vnev << " " << vek[i].knev << " " << vek[i].szulev << ". " << vek[i].szulhonap << ". " << vek[i].szulnap << endl;
}

int main()
{

    int n = vfmeret("szuletesi_nevlista.txt");
    szemelyadat* vektor;
    vektor = new szemelyadat[n];

    vfbeolv(vektor, n, "szuletesi_nevlista.txt");

    vfkiir(vektor, n);

    delete[] vektor;

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I need to cout the count of the unique elements which is in the "vek[i].szulev"

please help me somebody, how can I do this ?

Comment: Include the code in the question. Don't link to it.

Comment: I assume you are forbidden from using std::map (since you are not using std::vector).

Comment: Your question title is misleading, since there is no usage of `vector` in your program.

Comment: And if you really were using `std::vector`, then the whole program is 2 lines:  `std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,1,1,3}; std::cout << std::set<int>(v.begin(), v.end()).size();`

Comment: But I need to do on that way, I can't use vector in the task.

Comment: @Vettel.Sebastian Your code contains things that have absolutely nothing to do with counting elements.  You have input statements, output statements, and all sorts of other unrelated things.  The comment (and answer) given assumes you have all of the items in a container.  All you have to do is fill the `set` with the items in the container (using a loop starting from the first element and up to the last element and calling `std::set::insert`) and let the `std::set` do the counting for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one simple way to count the unique values in a vector:

```
using Size = ptrdiff_t;

template< class Item >
auto n_unique_items( vector<Item> const& v )
    -> Size
{ return set<Item>{ v.begin(), v.end() }.size(); }
```

Comment: if you find it difficult to adapt then please ask a new question about that. anyway, you ***asked*** for how to count the unique items in a vector. i disregarded your example code since it didn't include vectors.

Answer (score 2):

Since you insisted on using "your code", you can still utilize `std::set` to do the counting.

It all boils down to this:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

void count_items(szemelyadat* vek, int elemszam)
{
    std::set<int> counter;
    for (int i = 0; i < elemszam; i++)
          counter.insert(vek[i].szulev);
    std::cout << "The number of unique items is " << counter.size();
}
```

If you call the `count_items` once you fill your "vektor", then this will give you then unique number of `szulev` in the vektor.

Comment: Sorry for the edit and rollback, I haven't got to my first cup of coffee yet. Just sorry.